# JavaFX 21 IntelliJ Idea non modular with Maven application on Windows 10, how to run (Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing...)

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, java-21

When I use [this code](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/IDE/IntelliJ/Non-Modular/Maven) locally :

- I can build and compile
- I cannot Run, because I've got this error :

  - **Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application.**

I'd like to understand why all the dependencies are in my maven project and the path to the JDK is ok.

Comment: Did you run your project by executing the `javafx:run` Maven goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks `@SLaw`, it's my fault, I found the error with **`mvn javafx:run -X`**, the maven compiler plugin of mainClass in the build, was not the right one.